# React Query keeps retrying despite 'enabled' set to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I want to set up my query so that it retries infinitely unless it receives a particular type of an error, such as 404 or 401. I couldn't find a way to do it with React Query API, but I figured I can provide a callback setting `enabled` to false to my fetch wrapper like so:

```
async function fetchItems(onError) {
  return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/404").then(async (response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return await response.json();
    } else {
      if (response.status === 404) onError();
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(true);
  const { data } = useQuery(
    "data",
    () => fetchItems(() => setIsEnabled(false)),
    {
      enabled: isEnabled,
      retry: true
    }
  );

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cartwright-54e88?file=/src/App.js)

This, however, doesn't work and it keeps on retrying despite `enabled` being set to false right after the first call. Am I doing something wrong, does it work as designed or should I file a bug report?

Comment: try this: 
      {enabled: !isEnabled,
      retry: true
    }

Comment: @Sakshi no, my goal is not to disable the query completely so that it doesn't run at all, which your settings would cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

retry takes also a function with `count`, `error` params. query will rerun if function on `retry` returns truthy. in this way you need to throw status at your fetch function and implement a boolean logic like:

```
if (response.status === 404) onError();
throw new Error(response.status);
...
retry: (count, {message: status}) => (status !== '404' && status !== '401')
```