# How to repeatedly send request to a same API using react-query?

Tags: typescript, react-query

I want to use react-query to send the request and check a field of the response right after. Once I found the field I need in the response, stop doing more action. Otherwise, keep executing the request again until I find the field.

```
const queryResult = useQuery({ queryKey: ['test','testDataId'], queryFn: ({queryKey}) => fetchTestData(queryKey[1]),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clue that might be helpful: [react-query QueryClient](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/QueryClient)

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const queryKey = ['test','testDataId'];

const queryResult = useQuery({ 
  queryKey,
  queryFn: ({queryKey}) => fetchTestData(queryKey[1]),
  // Adjust the `responseData` structure,can be omitted.
  select: (result) => result.data,
  onSuccess(responseData){
    if (responseData.refreshing === true) {
      // Crucial action, mark the query with queryKey as staled
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey})
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way also you can try by adding retry params and also manage the delay through retryDelay:

ex.

```
const result = useQuery({
  queryKey,
  queryFn: ({queryKey}) => fetchTestData(queryKey[1]),
  retry: 10, // Will retry failed requests 10 times before displaying an error
})
```

You can also add a function in it for manage based on status

```
const result = useQuery({
  queryKey,
  queryFn: ({queryKey}) => fetchTestData(queryKey[1]),
  retry: (count, {message: status}) => (status !== '404' && status !== '401')
  // You can add logic based on your requirement and status code.
})
```

references link:

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-retries

[React Query keeps retrying despite 'enabled' set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209420/react-query-keeps-retrying-despite-enabled-set-to-false)

Comment: A good and simple idea. But it seems I have to throw an error manually to trigger the retry function. It might not suitable for my real coding situation, but helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `invalidateQueries`, which will mark the current data as stale and trigger a re-fetch in the background (as long as you don't pass it `refetchType: 'none'`).

In your `onSuccess`, add this (wrapped in the check for the field you are looking for):

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [queryKey] });
```